# Quarkus Panache Mongo entity with Javax Units

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm writing an application that needs to keep track of various amounts of stuff with differing units of measurement.

I would like to store this measurement data with the help of [javax.measure, and a reference implementation from tec.units](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-measure)

The problem here is that Panache/ Mongo does not seem to know how to process the datatypes. For instance:

```java
...
import javax.measure.Unit;
...


@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@MongoEntity(collection = "inventoryItem")
public class InventoryItem extends PanacheMongoEntity {
    ...
    private Unit capMeasurement;

}
```

Will yield the following of I attempt to persist the class:

```
Cannot use 'TransformedUnit' with the PojoCodec.: java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl and java.lang.Class are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I also have trouble with the objects in the (lombok generated) `equals()`/`toString()` for the following error:

```
javax/measure/format/ParserException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/measure/format/ParserException
    at tec.units.ri.AbstractUnit.toString(AbstractUnit.java:211)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at com.ebp.openQuarterMaster.baseStation.data.items.InventoryItem.toString(InventoryItem.java:14)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Formatter.java:3031)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2908)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.encode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:53)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SplittablePayload$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(SplittablePayload.java:200)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SplittablePayload$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(SplittablePayload.java:187)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writeDocument(BsonWriterHelper.java:77)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:162)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:490)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:202)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:431)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:251)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:194)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:620)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1009)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:470)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:447)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime.MongoOperations.persist(MongoOperations.java:207)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime.MongoOperations.persist(MongoOperations.java:57)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.PanacheMongoEntityBase.persist(PanacheMongoEntityBase.java:36)
    at com.ebp.openQuarterMaster.baseStation.data.items.InventoryItemTest.testEquals(InventoryItemTest.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:925)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:831)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.measure.format.ParserException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:428)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:378)
    ... 134 more
```

I am wondering if the core issue is the same here.

One way I was thinking about getting around this was by simply mapping a string value to the constants in the library and storing that string value, but was unsure if anyone knew of a perhaps more compatible library/implementation.

For reference, using the following dependencies:

```
    compile 'javax.measure:unit-api:2.1.2'
    compile 'tec.units:unit-ri:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about javax.measure but MongoDB with Panache uses the POJO Codec of MongoDB to transform your object to a BSON document.

If this codec is not able to transform your object to a BSON document, you need to create a dedicated codec for the type that causes the issue. This codec will be automatically picked up by Quarkus and registered to the MongoDB client.

You can read the following section about MongoDB codec usage in Quarkus: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec

Comment: could we maybe improve the error message? `Cannot use 'TransformedUnit' with the PojoCodec + cryptic error` is not that helpful.

Comment: The issue is with the POJO codec (or lombok as both error are reported) and the way they handle some complex types. I cannot see any way to improve the message from Quarkus side.

Comment: Such issue can also be met when running in Native mode due to the pojo class being dropped at compilation. Adding @RegisterForReflection or registering the class in the reflection json configuration can fix the issue. Why that specific pojo class is dropped while i have many other similar POJO classes not dropped and used by same mongo entity is for me a mystery.